# Android: How to encrypt your own database in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to build an app that uses an already created db ... I already found a tutorial on

how to copy it to the corect location so it can be used by a ContentProvider.But the problem

is that I also need to protect that data ...I already found SQLCipher which is supposed to

protected the db ... but none of the samples I found mentions on how to copy your own. I

keep gettin an error the ContentProvider was not found .. .

Comment: Who are you trying to "protect that data" from?

Comment: I do not want it to be accessible to everyone as if you have root access you can access your data folders where all the databases are

Comment: Anyone who has the intelligence to root the device will have the intelligence to find your baked-in encryption key for the database. If you do not want the user having access to some files, do not put the files on the user's phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution I managed to build my database using either an sqlCipher tool or either exporting the db as SQLite commands and then creating the new Ciphered database using the SQLCipher libs...and getReadableDatabse and getWritableDatabase did not work for me I had to use openDatabase and pass RWR FLAG it is strange that SQLCipher implements them because I couldn't get them to work ... do not know if I have been clear enough ... if anyone else has this problem he can let me know.